# Changing a directive template according to data in attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, dynamic, angularjs-directive

I am trying to access an attribute - tab title from html into my directive and according to that the directive should change the html template.
Below is the code
HTML

```js
 .directive('contentItem', function($compile) {
   var locationTemplate = '<div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-6 form-horizontal" style="border:1px solid"><select id="location" ng-change="detailCtlr.getLocation()" class="form-control" ng-model="detailCtlr.locSelected"><option ng-repeat="option in detailCtlr.typeArr" value="{{option.typeId}}">{{option.type}}</option></select></div></div></div>';
   var peopleTemplate = '<div class="container">klfdjsfsjldjs</div>';

   var getTemplate = function(contentType) {


     switch (contentType) {
       case 'Locations':
         template = locationTemplate;
         break;
       case 'People':
         template = peopleTemplate;
         break;

     }

     return template;
   }

   var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {
     console.dir(scope.content);

     element.html(getTemplate(scope.content)).show();

     $compile(element.contents())(scope);

   }

   return {
     //       template: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
     //           console.log("in template");
     //           console.log(tAttrs.content);
     //           console.dir(tAttrs.content);
     //            console.log("making templte");
     //     
     //         
     //            return getTemplate(tAttrs.content);
     //        },
     restrict: "E",
     replace: true,
     link: linker,
     scope: {
       content: '='
     }
   };
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<uib-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" select="Ctlr.getTabInfo(tab.title,$index)" active="" heading="{{tab.title}}">

  <content-item content="tab.title"></content-item>

</uib-tab>
```

I am being able to access the content "tab.title" in linker function however,the angularJS linked code using {{detailCtlr.getLocation()}} code doesnt work.If I directly return the html in template the code works but there is no way to get the "tab.title" value...I tried a bunch of things like changing the scope,passing an $index to identify the tab but nothing seems to be working..Any suggestions?Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a typical example of where you should explain what you want to achieve rather than ask for a specific solution. Usually when you try to switch between different templates in a directive you are doing something wrong. A directive should have 1 template - and rather include sub-directives depending on logic.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are putting to much responsibility on one directive, if you try to split it up in multiple directives it will be much easier. One directive for the container - and then include subdirectives with the different pages, using ng-if to choose which directive to show.

The template of your directive could be something like this:

```
<div>
    <page-info ng-if="content == 'info'"></page-info>
    <page-about ng-if="content == 'about'"></page-about>
    <page-login ng-ig="content == 'login'"></page-login>
</div>
```

You would then need to create a separate directive for each page.

Comment: Thanks @Etse ..what I am trying to do is get different HTML content to show depending on the tab selected.i.e depending on value in "tab.title" ..I was trying to get this value as an attribute in the directive and then change the directive template accordingly ...I tried two things -

Comment: The solution is not to change the actual template - but rather do as I show above. Depending on the tab.title value, include different different content in the directive. (for instance if `tab.title == 'info' I would include the page-info directive)

Comment: 1. Using template - if I return HTML directly in the template directly it works but there is not way to get it according to condition "tab.title"..Tried template function but couldnt get the attribute using attr.content..//please refer above code
2. Using link - I am able to get tab.title in this case..but the HTML that is returned back to the page doesnt show any angular stuff working in it i.e{{ctlr.option}} ..etc ..

Comment: Currently I am using similar solution as yours, of making different directives for each tab and it works..I was just wondering if there was a way of making it work through one directive..Thanks again!

Comment: there are ways to get it to work. You could hook up on the compile-stage in the lifecycle in the directive and manipulate the template. But it is considered bad practice, and you end up with code which is hard to reason about. I would not reccomend it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need any kind of workarounds, you can simply pass the directive template as as function injecting element and attributes, placing whatever processing you need inside it.

```
.directive('contentItem', function() {
   var directiveObj= {};

   directiveObj.template= function(element, attributes){

      if(attributes['contentType'] == 'Locations') 
          return locationTemplate;

      if(attributes['contentType'] == 'people') 
          return peopleTemplate;
   };

   //bla bla bla

   return directiveObject;
});
```